# Reading data values ​of a nested map in Angular

Tags: json.net

`I receive values ​​from an API that return a form

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic.ToList());
            return json;
```

I get the data in Angular like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Fb1.png)
I want to display the data in the browser, but cannot read the data

I created such an object in JS:
listData!: Map<number, Map<Job, number>>
And it is initialized in NGONINIT:

```
.subscribe(
          data => {
        
        this.listData=data})
```

In the HTML page I go through it like this:

```
<div class="viewing" *ngFor="let item of listData | keyvalue " >
       {{item.key}}{{item.value }}
        <div *ngFor="let i of item.value">
         {{i.keys}}
        </div>
```

But in the end I get the following result in the browser:
0 [object Object]`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post your response data as JSON snippet instead of image. Thanks.